# Chrome Browser defaults to Incognito setting

Tags: google-chrome, private-browsing

When I open Chrome it automatically goes into incognito setting.  How can I get it to open in regular format when I start Chrome?

Comment: Are you on Windows? If yes, right click on the Chrome shortcut from where you launch it and post the contents of the 'target' field.

Comment: How exactly do you open Chrome?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 11.05.  When I click on the shortcut for Chrome or if I use the general menu option I get the same behavior.

Answer (score 3):

If chrome is launching in 'incognito' mode then you should check the Properties of your desktop shortcut which you launching from.

[image: Properties for Google Chrome]

Check to see if the 'Target Field' has '-incognito' on the end (just like the picture above). If so then this is what will be causing your problem.

It is then just a simple case of removing the text and clicking 'Apply' to save your settings.